# Bazel: cc_binary can't locate headers in dependent cc_library

Tags: bazel

This particular aspect of building in something that Bazel ought to make far easier than it is. Google tries to make it clear but it doesn't seem to work. About 1/3rd of the way down the doc says:

```
foo.cc  can include both foo.h bar.h
```

because the cc_binary for "foo.cc" depends on the library "bar" and the library "bar" specifically lists bar.h in its hdrs section. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html.

The implication I draw then is,

- if the library here bar builds
- if the binary correctly calls out the library dependency here bar
- if the headers the binary need appear in the library's hdrs section
- if the library is visible to the binary

then the code in the binary (assuming no other unrelated issues) can include the library's headers.

My case satisfies all four preconditions. But when I build the binary, Bazel *doesn't even bother to put a -I in the command line* then summarily complains header not found! What gives?

```
-----------------
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
cc_library(
    name = "hello-time",
    srcs = ["mylib/src/hello-time.cc"],
    hdrs = glob(
            ["mylib/include/**/*.h"],
        ),
    copts = ["-Ilib/mylib/include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
-----------------
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["test/src/hello-world.cc"],
    deps = [
       "//lib:hello-time",
    ],
    stamp = 1,
)
```

What does it take to make Bazel actually leverage the dependency to find the right include paths?

```
tasks/test/src/hello-world.cc:1:10: fatal error: hello-time/hello-time.h: No such file or directory
#include <hello-time/hello-time.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

`copts` does not impact how depending `cc_binary` is built as per [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.copts):

> The flags take effect only for compiling this target, not its dependencies, so be careful about header files included elsewhere.

From what I see, the problem would be, that inside your `//lib` package, you have something like:

```
.
├── BUILD
└── mylib
    ├── include
    │   └── hello-time
    │       └── hello-time.h
    └── src
        └── hello-time.cc
```

But from `test/src/hello-world.cc` you are expecting to include `hello-time/hello-time.h` without the `mylib/include` prefix. That said, and assuming the layout is more or less fixed, you can use `strip_include_prefix` attribute in your `cc_library` target, so that it could look like this (based on your example; I would probably opt to not use `glob()` and list headers instead):

```
cc_library(
    name = "hello-time",
    srcs = ["mylib/src/hello-time.cc"],
    hdrs = glob(
            ["mylib/include/**/*.h"],
        ),
    strip_include_prefix = "mylib/include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cc_library entry add:

```
# note bazel will add dir prefix from root to
# the directory w/ BUILD in it for you.
includes = ["<dir>"...],
```

The doc https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html specifically points out Bazel will add -I paths for you for it *and* other targets which depend on it.